# Iterate nodes to get child key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

So here is how my test firebase looks

[image: Firebase structure]

I want to be able to go through the entire list and match the name with a string and if it matches, return the CID. This is what I'm trying from the official documentation but it returns undefined.

```
fb.on('value', function(snapshot){
  var data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data.name);     
})
```

If I log just snapshot.val() then it returns all of them in this format:

{CID: 'XXXXXX' , Name: 'XXXXX'}

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What are `fb` and `snapshot`?

Comment: `fb` is the reference to firebase location and `snapshot` is the dataSnapshot in the callback.

Comment: Where is the name you would like to match?

Comment: A user would pass that in at a later time. Problem is I cant get the name value from firebase to compare the strings.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear: please show the code where `fb` and `snapshot` are defined.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice snapshot is not defined anywhere. `var firebase = require('firebase');
var fb = new firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/');`

Comment: The official docs would recommend [using `child_added`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types) in most cases. If you want to work with 'value', you can use `snapshot.forEach()` for iterating. Also, [don't use array indices, use push ids](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push). Last but not least, you probably want to do this server-side with a [query](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Comment: `snapshot is not defined anywhere.` After taking a closer look, actually `snapshot` is defined here: `...function(snapshot)...`. It is the name of the parameter of the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should be using data.Name, not data.name

Comment: Tried it, still returns undefined

Comment: when you say it returns all of them, do you mean in an array?

Comment: Yes, they are in an array.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if it is an array, then you probably either want to iterate over it (eg, using forEach), or maybe you know that you want, for example, the 0th element, in which case you could just log data[0].Name.

Comment: Earlier I had tried this `fb.on('value', function(snapshot){
 snapshot.forEach(function(dataSnap){
  console.log(dataSnap.Name);
 })
})`

which gave me an error but I now tried this and it worked:
`fb.on('value', function(snapshot){
 var data = snapshot.val();
 data.forEach(function(dataSnap){
  console.log(dataSnap.Name);
 })
})`